# json column to gridview in yii2

Tags: json, gridview, yii2

I have a table:
id | name | values |

1  | John | {"data1":{"key1":"abs", "key2":"qwe"}, "data2":{"key1":"asd","key2":"obj"}}

in each row the json has different length. I need to create gridView like:

id | name | abs | asd | ...

1  | John | qwe | obj | ...

My code SqlDataProvider:

```
$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
            SELECT COUNT(id) FROM statistics', [':status' => 0])-     >queryScalar();
        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => 'SELECT id, name, value

                    FROM 
                    statistics',

            'totalCount' => $count,
            'key'        => 'id',
        ]);

    return $this->render('statistics',
    [   
        'dataProvider'      => $dataProvider,

    ]);
```

and GridView:

```
  GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'name',

        ],

    ]); ?>
```

When I add column 'vlues' the result was like:

1  | John | {"data1":{"key1":"abs", "key2":"qwe"}, "data2":{"key1":"asd","key2":"obj"}}

Please, help!

Comment: If you don't have many rows in that table, convert everything into a big array and use `ArrayDataProvider`.

Comment: Sounds like you want a table inside a table? I don't think gridview supports this. What you can do is make a custom column and parse your json to output an html table though.

Comment: @Beowulfenator Thank you!!! it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add value column like this

```
   'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        [
           'attribute' => 'data1',
           'value' => function($model){
              return (json_decode($model->value)->data1);
        }
       ],
    ],
```